# Appending backups while overwriting expired sets

Tags: sql-server, backup

I've been reading up on this, but the online documentation is a bit difficult to understand and seems awkwardly written.  For example the `INIT`, `NOINIT`. One says it will try to overwrite everything. The other says it will append regardless.

I want something in-between that. I want expired media sets to no longer be in the file, but for new backup jobs to append to the file along side any sets that have not yet expired.

Will the SQL below perform the desired backup?

```
BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] 
TO  DISK = N'c:\Backups\mydb.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'mydb-Full Database Backup', NOSKIP, 
NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10, RETAINDAYS = 60
GO
```

If I run the above, and there is a backup set older than 60 days, will it be removed from the file?

**Edit:**

In response to RichardTheKiwi's suggestion I have rewritten the code to create a new file each time.  I will then write a windows script to delete files older than a certain date

```
declare @filename varchar(max)
set @filename = 'c:\sqlbackups\pptd_' +  replace(replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 120),':','_'),' ','_') + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE [Peter's pointless test database] 
TO  DISK = @filename
WITH FORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'pptd-Full Database Backup', 
NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it for yourself on a non-important backup set?

Comment: Well I test ran it,  but I'll have to wait two months to know if it will do what I need it to.  I could change the retaindays to 1 and test it again tomorrow,  but that's slower and less reliable than asking db admin experts.

Comment: @MrVimes :-) "Reliable" = testing it out and having proof.

Comment: So rather than someone answering my question I have to alter the query to retain one day,  wait two days,  and see if today's backup has gone?

Comment: @MrVimes Not saying that at all.  By all means get input from us here, but I'd recommend testing out and seeing with your own eyes whatever answer you get.  A fact is something you can prove.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: Ok I will test.

Comment: @MrVimes The point I'm trying to get across is *by all means do take the word of the experts here*, but for reliability a test is always the best.  But....the professionals here will be able to help get you their experience.

Comment: I get that.  Thankyou.  I have set up a test.  I ran a backup today and I will run it again after 24 hours has passed (with retaindays = 1) and see if today's goes away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, that won't work.  It will keep appending but will leave the expired sets in the same archive.  This screenshot shows a backup archive using your script, set to `RETAINDAYS = 2`, run once in November (VM trickery) and again today.

[image]

I think what you're after is a rolling backup, so assuming this is weekly, then after a burn in period, it should retain 7 old backup sets, remove one and append a new one.

Personally, I would keep a single backup set per file and use the cleanup feature in the maintenance wizard to remove old files; that or a regular Windows Scheduled Task.  There shouldn't be any real need to keep backup sets in a single file.

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29455/limiting-sql-server-backups-inside-bak-file

Comment: Thankyou.  So would I have my backup script create a new filename each time (maybe with the date appended on the filename)?

Comment: @MrVimes Sounds like a perfect idea

Comment: FYI I've updated my question with a script to create a file each time.